# Is there any way to set what is returned when a variable is requested as is?

Tags: c#

Hullo,

For example if I had:

```
public class Fu
{
    int _bar;


    public Fu(){
        _bar = 12;
    }

    public void Square(){
        _bar *= _bar;
    }
}
```

(This is just an example by the way, I know this is the worst possible way of doing what I'm doing.)

Is there anyway that I could go:

```
Fu _fu = new Fu();
_fu.Square();
Console.WriteLine(_fu);
```

and _fu returns 144 instead of the class Fu? Or is that just a ridiculous question?

Regards,
Harold

**Edit:** `Console.WriteLine(_fu);` was a bad example. What if I wanted to do `int twelveCubed = 12 * _fu`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` has to convert the object to a string to print it; the default implementation uses the type's name, but you can override it:

```
public override string ToString() { return _bar.ToString(); }
```

or if (comment) you want a conversion operator:

```
public static implicit operator int(Fu fu) { return fu._bar; }
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it by default? As if I want it returned as an `int` but I was just using Console.WriteLine as an example

Comment: @Harold to do *what* by default? *what* do you want returned? the only method you have is `void`, so **nothing** is returned... You can, however, add an implicit static conversion operator, so this is valid: `int i = _fu;` - is that enough? That would also work with a method that takes `int` as a parameter, i.e. `SomeMethod(_fu);` (where the param is of type `int`)

Comment: Sorry, I've just realised how vague I've been being. And that static conversion operator sounds about right, how could I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Add this method in your Fu class

```
 public override string ToString()
 {
     return _bar.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it by default? As if I want it returned as an `int` but I was just using Console.WriteLine as an example

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method

```
public class Fu
{
    int _bar;


    public Fu()
    {
        _bar = 12;
    }

    public void Square()
    {
        _bar *= _bar;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _bar.ToString();
    }
}
```

If you want to automatically convert to `int` values you can create an cast operator

```
public class Fu
{
    int _bar;


    public Fu()
    {
        _bar = 12;
    }

    public void Square()
    {
        _bar *= _bar;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Fu f)
    {
        return f._bar;
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
Fu _fu = new Fu();
_fu.Square();
int intVal = _fu;
Console.WriteLine(intVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're looking for [implicit operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx), which allows you to implement an operator that provides a user-defined type conversion. In this case, you could define an implicit conversion between the `Fu` class and type `int`, where an instance of the class `Fu` would behave exactly like a value of type `int`.

For example, adding the following method to your class will make your code work exactly as suggested:

```
public static implicit operator int(Fu fu)
{
   return fu._bar;
}
```

I advise you to be *very careful* when implementing features like this! They can often be confusing to consumers of your class, and should *only* be implemented when the conversion is guaranteed not to cause a loss of data.

Answer (score 0):

C# is not like old Visual Basic where controls had the concept of DefaultProperty so

```
MsgBox(TextBox1)
```

was exactly the same as:

```
MsgBox(TextBox1.Text)
```

in my opinion what you are asking does not make much sense and if it did and it worked, I still would not use it. How can we specify what should be returned and what if we change the class implementation and then we break everything without compile time errors?!

Comment: See scorpio's answer - it can be done with ToString() and it's useful for debugging. BCL classes like Point, for example, override ToString().

Comment: question title says when variable is requested as is, not when variable is used as string... that's why I have given this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Quetion must be clear, give some more details?**

anyways

why not you trying the Properties of class.

```
 public class Fu
{
   private int _bar;
    public Fu()
    {
        _bar = 12;
    }
    public void Square()
    {
       _bar *=_bar;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _bar.ToString();
    }
}
```

And call them as

```
       Fu fu = new Fu();
        fu.Square();
        Console.WriteLine(fu);
```